# Sort matrix rows iteratively according to sum of some columns

Tags: matrix

I have a matrix say

```
matinitial =
  {{41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 410},
   {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 10},
   {21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 210},
   {31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 310}};
```

I want to form matrices `matfinal[i],` 
  where i runs from 1 to 6 in this example.My `matfinal[i]` should be equal to matinitial after sorting rows based on sum 
of columns from `i` to `i + 4`.
  I tried the following codes :

```
Do[matfinal[i] = SortBy[matinitial,Total[matinitial[[All, i ;; i + 4]], {2}]], {i, 1, 6}];
```

But I do not get the results I desire.
For example, my matfinal[1] should be equal to matinitial sorted based on Total of first 
four columns:

```
{41 + 42 + 43 + 44, 11 + 12 + 13 + 14, 21 + 22 + 23 + 24, 31 + 32 + 33 + 34} = {170, 50, 90, 130}.
```

Therefore,

```
matfinal[1]={{11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 10},
            {21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 210},
            {31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 310},
            {41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 410}};
```

Please note,  in my real world problem my matinitial matrix is 100 by 20000 in 
size.Any help is greatly appreciated.And also, 
  thank you for your help in advance!! :))

Comment: Please format your code. I did it before you deleted this exact question and then reposted it. I'm not going to format the same code twice.

Comment: Update: Please observe how Algohi formatted your question, and next time do the same.

Comment: What does "sorting rows based on sum of columns from i to i + 4" mean? Could you give us an example of how such sorting is done on a matrix and what the expected result looks like?

Comment: In your latest edit, did you mean first `four` column or `five`? If `i = 1`, `i + 4 = 5` so I think it should be the first five column.

Comment: @ seismatica, I think my issue is solved in either way. I just want to sort matrix based on sum of some columns. It could be sum of columns 1 to 4 or 1 to 5 or 4 to 7.

Answer (score 5):

You were almost there but you need to read up on `SortBy`:

```
Do[
 matfinal[i] = SortBy[matinitial, Total[#[[i ;; i + 4]]] &],
 {i, 6}
 ]
```

Comment: is sorting based on sum of columns from i to i+4 or sum of rows from i to i+4. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @rkadhikari Column `i` to column `i+4` because in the second argument `#` represents a row.

Comment: Sorry I just evaluated `matfinal` from your answer and since I wasn't seeing anything I thought there was an error on yours and started to work on my answer. Now I see what you're trying to get at. I also did some [benchmarking](http://i.stack.imgur.com/etDbO.png) and `Do` seems to be faster as well compared to other methods that I tried, probably because it generates one list at a time. I will delete my answer.

Comment: @Pickett, thank you so much. I am working on my data. I will keep you posted as soon as I figure out on my data.

Comment: @Pickett, Thank you so much. I think it serves my purpose.

Comment: @rkadhikari ok, I'm glad to hear it. I noticed you didn't accept the answer you got on your question yesterday. After a question has been out for a while and no new answers are trickling in you should accept the answer that you think is best.

Comment: Can anyone please add more light to on this issue. Thanks @Pickett for your codes. I am trying to extend your codes by putting some restrictions. While running Pickett's codes, how can we omit some  values that are out of range in some columns withing column range in each do loop. For example, while running above codes, I want to exclude some columns within [#[[i ;; i + 4]]] which has values less than -100. Expecting some help.

Comment: @rkadhikari Just for sorting or do you want to omit those values in the final lists as well? This is to perform the sort without using those elements: `With[{l=#},Total@Select[l[[i;;i+4]],# > -100 &]]&` - use it as the second argument to `SortBy`.

Comment: @Pickett, your codes saved my tons of time.  Thank you so much. That's what I was trying to do for last 4 hours and you did it in seconds.

Answer (score 4):

```
func = Function[{mat, matfin, n, m},
  Table[
    With[{ord = Ordering[mat, All, Total[#[[i ;; i + m]]] < Total[#2[[i ;; i + m]]] &]},
    matfin[i] = matinit[[ord]]], {i, n}]];
```

OP's example:

```
func[matinitial, matfinal, 6, 4];
matfinal[1]
(*  {{11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 10}, 
     {21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 210}, 
     {31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 310}, 
     {41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 410}} *)
```

Example 2:

```
initmat = RandomInteger[100, {4, 6}];
initmat // TableForm[#, TableHeadings -> {Array["r" <> ToString[#] &, {4}], 
                                           Array["c" <> ToString[#] &, {6}]}] &
```

[image]

```
func[initmat, finmat, 4, 2];
finmat[3]
(* {{19, 59, 6, 1, 36, 59}, 
    {99, 75, 25, 49, 12, 10}, 
    {79, 59, 23, 21, 88, 2}, 
    {42, 10, 13, 97, 83, 84}} *)

Column[(TableForm[MapAt[Style[#, Red, Bold] &, finmat[#], {{All, # ;; # + 2}}], 
           TableHeadings -> {Array["r" <> ToString[#] &, {4}], 
                            Array["c" <> ToString[#] &, {6}]}]) & /@ Range[4], 
       Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time. Its fancy and works. Great job!!!

Comment: thank you @rkadhikari, glad it worked for you.